# Einstein Content Selection / not matched attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, einstein, einstein-recommendations

I think I´ve learned that you can stear the asset by mapping the attributes of the send DE with the attributes of the asset. E.g. country "france" must match exactly. Now I can let rotate content in the fitting frame.

So far so good. Now I want to use einstein to give the customer the most fitting banner out of 10 possible categories (e.g. shirts, shoes, cosmetics ...). 
Of course I have an idea about his preferences and that information in the send-DE, but I'm hoping that the feature can support me.
How can I set the mapping that einstein will learn and improve the promoted banner?
Sorry for the unspecific question but I need to get the approach of the feature to use it.

my best guess ist to configure it like that: 
[image]

Comment: Maybe you wanna read the documentation on [fatigue roles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_set_fatigue_rules.htm&type=5), btw. welcome on stackexchange as german speaking user ;)

Comment: :-) thanks. The fatigue rules are quit nice but I´m asking myself how Einstein know which asset class (asset class = category) is the most fitting? Is there some kind of a asset class rotation (test & learn) and it learns what is the most fitting asset class for customer with the Consumer attribute SGF xy?

Comment: So ECS uses a multi-arm bandit to determine best asset to use. If you want a personalized recommendation per subscriber I would suggest Email recommendations

Answer (score 0):

"As subscribers open your messages, Einstein analyzes click results to find out which assets spark interest in customers. Using real-time analysis, Einstein finds the assets that prompt customers to click a link in the email. As analysis proves that an asset continually contributes to increased click rates, Einstein selects that asset more frequently while the send proceeds." https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_einstein_content_selection.htm